# Django User Registration register.html returns a blank page

Tags: django

I'm a beginner and i have been stuck on this for two days.Here is what i presently have in **my views files**.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.core.context_processors import csrf


def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/successful/')

#    args = {}
#    args.update(csrf(request))
#    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
#    return render_to_response('registration/register.html', args)

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {'form': form,})


def main_page(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def logout_page(request):
    """
    Log users out and re-direct them to the main page.
    """
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')# Create your views here.

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html')
```

**In my urls file**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from mysiteII.views import *
admin.autodiscover()


    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysiteII.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', main_page),

# Login / logout.

    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_page),

# Web portal.

    url(r'^portal/', include('portalapp.urls')),

    #Serve static content.

    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                {'document_root': 'static'}),

    url(r'^register/$', registration),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),


    url(r'^successful/$', success),
)
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

    <!-- # {% block title %}Create an account{% endblock %} -->

{% block content %}

    <h2>Create an account</h2>

    <form action = "/register/" method = "post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

    <input type="submit" value="Create Account" />

    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Looks as if the register.html doesnt render forms.ProbAbaly i missed out on something.Please someone to point the right direction.Thank you, lot of Appreciation.

Comment: If you use chrome or FF, in the "Network" tab of the developer toolbar, do you see a 200 for register url ?

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing a block named "content" in the base.html file? Can you confirm if it is showing the "register.html" template (try using django-debug-toolbar to see the templates loaded. The form should show with the code you have written.

Comment: Oops,i'll check that rightaway.brb

Comment: Thanks a bunch Laidibug,you were right.I only added the block content and "Bham!!!" you nailed it.To karthikr , a big thank you to you also.

Comment: Glad to help, I'll formulate an answer so it doesn't get left in the comments for others.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to debug this is to make sure you are rendering the proper template, usually this can be done with [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). In this case the register.html template is indeed being loaded. From there check your blocks. It's possible that you don't have a "content" block in your base.html.